# How do I change target of symlink in windows

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Is it possible to change the target of a symlink or junction in Windows? In Linux it can be modified with:

```
ln -f
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With Windows [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) installed, you can right-click on the link in Windows Explorer and check the properties. There is a tab that allows you to change the link directly.

Sorry I can't say if this is possible without the extension installed as it is one of the first things I install after Windows.

The Windows command link tool `mklink` does not allow this.

There are, however, Windows equivalents for Linux commands. ln.exe is one:

- http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
- http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html
- http://neosmart.net/Symlinks/
- http://www.mkssoftware.com/

Comment: This solution seems to work however I didn't test it thoroughly.

Comment: wow! Link Shell Extension, also notably, includes a **Symbolic Link Driver
for Windows XP** among it's downloads.

Comment: `mklink` would be the Windows-integrated command for linking (symbolic and hard).

Comment: @Jinxed, I already said that mklink doesn't do what the OP asked.

Comment: The windows Methodology for changing the location of a softlink using MKLINK is to delete the link (Using `RD /Q` if a directory link, or `Del /F /Q` if a file link) and recreate it uisang MKLINK.  eg  `RD /Q "C:\Link\Folder" && MKLINK /D "C:\Link\Folder" "C:\Some\New\Target\Folder"`  and  `Del /F /Q "C:\Link\File Link" && MKLINK "C:\Link\File Link.ext" "C:\Some\New\Target\File here.ext"`  This is also True for Junctions and Hard Links.

Answer (score 9):

Powershell

```
New-Item -Type SymbolicLink -Path "C:\linkpath" -Target "C:\newtarget" -Force
```

Mind the `-Force` Luke

P.S. elevated mode required

Answer (score 5):

Just remove and recreate the link.  That's all that -f does in Linux anyway.

Also, here's a cool [Windows Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html).

Answer (score 3):

The method belo works for me in Windows 7

```
mklink TempLink NewTarget

copy /l /y TempLink OldLink

del TempLink
```

Comment: This worked for me on Windows Server 2012 R2. The important part is `copy /L` which preserves symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the symlink is a hanging symlink, i.e. points to a nonexistent location, then using linkshell extension will not allow you to edit the target, because this works as an extension to explorer which adds a tab to the properties context menu.  If the symlink is hanging, explorer signals an error and will not allow you to access the link properties, and hence you will not be able to edit the target location.