# How can I copy folder containing Relative Symbolink Link to another drive without replacing Link?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link, copy

Using `Windows 10`, I have created a folder named `Products` in which I add new folders for each product I buy.

On my PC `Products` folder is similar to

```
LG.Television
Ryobi.Sprayer
Epson.Scanner
Dell.PC
```

Then I have created some special folders which names begin with `@` and that I use to regroup some products together

On my PC, I have

```
@Entertainment
@Computer
    Epson.Scanner
    Dell.PC
@Home
@Do-it-yourself
```

In `@Computer`, I have created 2 **Relative** Symbolic Link as visible just above.

This work perfectly as I want. When I click on `Dell.PC` (Symbolic Link) in `@COmputer` folder, original `Dell.PC` folder is correctly open.

BUT when I copy `Products` folder to another disk for backup purpose using Paste/Copy, all my links are transformed to directories with files. The original directories (and all files in them) are now duplicated in archive folder.

Question:

Using DOS command, how can I do to copy `Products` directory on another drive KEEPING Symbolic Links ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change target of symlink in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/444016/how-do-i-change-target-of-symlink-in-windows)

Comment: No, your answer proposal doesn't respond to my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to copy a complete folder that exists on drive D: using following XCOPY Dos command

```
xcopy /B/I/E +Products c:\Archive\+Products
```

I navigated to a copied Symbolic Link and, using [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html), I can see in `Lien` (=Link) tab that Relative Symbolic Link has been copied as wanted.

[image]

Warning: on my PC, XCOPY command must be started as Administrator !
When not, Symbolic Link are not copied !